# How to convert Vector to z rotation angle

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, stage3d, x3d

Please help.

My camera orientation on 3D max is:

```
90 -30 0
```

When I export to X3D file it will have this orientation:

```
0, 0, -1, -0.524
```

And I can easily convert this to the angle of the camera
on the z axis like this:

```
-1 * -0.524 * 180/Math.PI = 30;
```

**Problem:**

But when I rotate the camera on 3D max to:

```
90 -30 90
```

on X3D I get this vector:

```
-0.251, 0.935, -0.251,-1.638
```

How can I figure out the value of z angle?

Comment: I'm not familiar X3d format but you need to figure out why using same values in each orientation gives different results... First time x-y `90, -30` gives `0, 0` is that right? So why suddenly the 2nd time, same x-y values of `90, -30` now gives `-0.251, 0.935`? It's strange...

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do it in Stage3D, probably the same on other platforms:

first you create an empty matrix3D:

```
var m3d:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();
```

then you rotate it with the given orientation vector from the X3D file:

```
m3d.appendRotation(v.w*180/Math.PI,new Vector3D(v.x,v.y,v.z));
```

decompose the matrix

```
var angles:Vector3D = m3d.decompose("eulerAngles")[1];
```

you get xyz angles in radians so turn radians to degrees:

```
var _z:Number = angles.z*180/Math.PI;
```